# Conjugación pronominal del verbo "ver"

Tags: verbos, conjugación

Me ha costado trabajo encontrar información sobre las conjugaciones pronominales (pareciera que no existieran oficialmente)

En especifico la que me cuesta trabajo encontrar son las del verbo "ver"

1. Veme
2. Vete
3. Vele
4. Vela
5. Velo
6. Venos/Veanos
7. Véanlos

Estas conjugaciones son correctas ?

Comment: Un verbo pronominal es el que usa los pronombres reflexivos (***me, te, se, nos, os, se***), http://roble.pntic.mec.es/acid0002/index_archivos/Gramatica/verbo_%20pronominal.htm

Comment: El uso de los pronombres después de los verbos se llama enclisis, ¿querrías preguntar más sobre la colocación de los pronombres o los pronombres que se tienen que usar)

Comment: creo que nisiquiera es enclsis... creo que enrealida se trata del imperativo de verte a ti mismo

Comment: Es que hay tres (o incluso cuatro) conceptos que hab surgido aquí y so puedes aclarar la pregunta podemos ayudarte más. Tenemos los verbos pronominales (/reflexivos), el posicionamiento de los pronombres (enclisis), la formación del imperativo (mandatos) y tal vez también la ortografía de los verbos con enclíticos (reglas para las tildes).

Comment: @guifa gracias.. creo que esto solo es la conjugación en imperativo del verbo "verse" y creo que verse es la conjugación pronominal del verbo ver... creí que llevaba enclisis por que como se agrega el sujeto al final del verbo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contesto aquí según los esclarecimientos en los comentarios.

Los verbos pronominales no son precisamente especiales en cuanto a conjugaciones.  La regla básica es que los conjugas como si no fuesen pronominales, y de acuerdo con [unas reglas bastante complicadas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12249/4182), pones el pronombre reflexivo que corresponde a la forma bien antes (*proclisis*) o después (*enclisis*) del verbo.<sup>1</sup>  En el caso de los mandatos, cuando son *afirmativos* el pronombre siempre es *enclítico*, es decir, va pegado después del verbo.  Con la mayoría de los verbos, ello nos obliga escribir una tilde:

> *duerme* → *duérmete*

Pero el caso de los verbos monosilábicos puede ser diferente.  En el caso de *ver*, tenemos las siguientes formas imperativas:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  yo: …*  │ nosotros/as: VEAMOS ┃ 
┠──────────┼─────────────────────┨
┃  tú: VE  │ vosotros/as: VED    ┃
┃ vos: VE  │                     ┃     * No existe ningún
┠──────────┼─────────────────────┨       imperativo en la
┃  Vd: VEA │     ustedes: VEAN   ┃       primera persona
┗━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛       singular.
```

A estos lo único que tenemos que hacer, caso sea en afirmativo, es agregar al final el pronombre reflexivo que serían los siguientes:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  yo: ME │ nosotros/as: NOS ┃ 
┠─────────┼──────────────────┨
┃  tú: TE │ vosotros/as: OS  ┃
┃ vos: TE │                  ┃
┠─────────┼──────────────────┨
┃  Vd: SE │     ustedes: SE  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Pero al agregarlos, tenemos que mantener la acentuación original del verbo y, en el caso del imperativo de *nosotros<sub>/as</sub>* y de *vosotros<sub>/as</sub>*, hay que quitar la *-s* o *-d* final.  Entonces en la forma informal (tanto tuteante como voseante), tenemos *ve* + *te* y hemos de conservar el acento en la *e*.  Como *vete* lo conserva allí, no tenemos que hacer nada.  Pero con la forma formal, tenemos *vea* + *se*, con obligación de mantener el acento en la *e*.  Como *vease* se acentúa en la *a*, hay que tildar la primera *e*: *véase*.  Al final acabamos con las siguientes formas:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  yo: …     │ nosotros/as: VEÁMONOS ┃ 
┠────────────┼───────────────────────┨
┃  tú: VETE  │ vosotros/as: VEOS     ┃
┃ vos: VETE  │                       ┃
┠────────────┼───────────────────────┨
┃  Vd: VÉASE │     ustedes: VÉANSE   ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

También, es de notar que la forma informal de *vete* fácilmente se puede confundir con la misma forma del verbo *irse*, por lo que más contexto puede ser necesario, por ejemplo, *vete en el espejo* o parecido.

---

<sup>1</sup> E incluso en el español medieval para los tiempos futuro y condicional, en el medio del verbo (*mesoclisis*).

Comment: No se como regalarte mas puntos pero esta respuesta es sumamente hermosa. el motivo de mi pregunta es por que llevo tiempo escribiendo un libro y el "Vete" me empezó a confundir y no estaba seguro si era correcto o no. ahora Veos me parece una solución mucho mejor. sin embargo no creo que funcione dentro del lenguaje del personaje que la usa (centroamericano, puesto que en américa no se utilizo el español medieval). aunque me haz provisto de un grandioso recurso , mil gracias !

Answer (score 2):

Aprendí a hacer este tipo de verbo jugando Scrabble - este tipo de verbo es súper útil para sacar el premio de los 50 puntos (usar todas las letras).

Yo: véome (me veo)
Tú: veste (te ves)
Él etc.: vese (se ve)
Nosotros: vémosnos (nos vemos)
Vosotros: veisos (os veis)
Ustedes: vense (se ven)
Ellos etc.: vense (se ven)

¿Querías también el subjuntivo?  P. ej. *véanse* (que Uds. se vean)?

Comment: Los españoles utilizan la segunda persona del plural: Vosotros: veisos y os veis. Es todo un pais, ¿verdad? Pero en todo caso, la primera forma que has puesto no suele decirse tanto. Es la segunda que se suele escuchar....

Comment: @Lambie - En general, ninguna de estas formas se usan en conversación (pero sí en Scrabble!).  // Si no puse la forma para *vosotros* fue porque temía hacerlo mal -- no fue por otra cosa....  Te invito a colaborar con un edit.

Comment: No creo que sea verdad eso. verse (del verbo verse como noséqué) se utiliza con mucha frecuencia. Lo poco frecuente es tu primera forma. Puse el vosotros pero la líneas no cuadran. Me sale un doble espacio.

Comment: Gracias, @Lambie.  Aprendí hace poco un truco.  Si agregas dos espacios al final de la línea, te da el "punto y aparte" con renglón cerrado. // ¿No crees que sea verdad qué cosa, perdón?  // Sí, el infinitivo *verse* es común, y "te ves" is común, pero "veste" etc. *no* es común.

Comment: ¿Hay algunas fuentes que subsanen la existencia de estas formas? Nunca las he visto. Google no me dió muchos resultados por "véome".