# Preguntas sobre "habías encontrado un regalo y comprádomelo"

Tags: gramática, pronombres

En esta cadena [Personal pronouns: When to hook at the end of verb and when to keep separate?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12235/23475), en la respuesta de user0721090601 observé el uso siguiente de los pronombres:

"*habías encontrado un regalo y comprádo**melo***"

user0721090601 escribó que esa situación es increíblemente rara (y yo entiendo el porqué). De hecho, yo mismo nunca lo encontraba en ningún fuente. En relación con esto, dos preguntas:

1. Eso es cierto que esta oración es correcta?
2. Sería correcto tambíen decir con el mismo significado lo siguiente:

a) "*Habías encontrado un regalo y **me lo** comprado*"?

Supongo que esto es incorrecto (el verbo "*haber*" tendría que ser usado otra vez antes de "*comprado*").

b) "*Habías encontrado un regalo y **me lo** habías comprado*"

Supongo que esto es correcto (pero yo escribiría "*me lo has comprado*" para respetar la cronología. O no es necesario porque ambas accionés ocurren casi al mismo tiempo?).

c) "***Me lo** habías encontrado un regalo y comprado*"

Supongo que esto es incorrecto (el verbo "*haber*" tendría que ser usado otra vez antes de "*comprado*" debido a que "*un regalo*" separa ambos verbos).

d) "***Me lo** habías encontrado un regalo y habías comprado*"

Supongo que esto es correcto (pero yo escribiría "*has comprado*" para respetar la cronología. O no es necesario porque ambas accionés ocurren casi al mismo tiempo?).

e) "***Me lo** habías encontrado y comprado un regalo*"

Supongo que esto es correcto (en este caso no necesita usar el verbo "*haber*" antes de "*comprado*" porque "*un regalo*" no separa ambos verbos).

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre tu primera pregunta: una frase como “habías encontrado un regalo y comprádomelo” es extremadamente rara; no es gramaticalmente incorrecta, pero nadie habla ni escribe así en español actualmente. En el [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos#3f) se aclara

> f) En el español actual, **el participio no admite con normalidad la agregación de pronombres enclíticos**; por ello, deben evitarse hoy usos como *Había prometídole su apoyo*, en lugar del normal *Le había prometido su apoyo*. (...) Solo es admisible la agregación de enclíticos a un participio **cuando aparece en coordinación con otro y no se repite el auxiliar**: *«Y después de haber adorado a Dios y dádole gracias, se sentaron»* (Somers Retrato [Ur. 1990]).

Tu ejemplo es precisamente el caso mencionado como excepción admisible, pero en realidad, lo más probable es que un hablante actual prefiriera repetir el auxiliar *haber*. Es decir, la forma normal y habitual de expresar esta idea es usar la opción (b) de las que propones más abajo.

Todas las otras opciones son gramaticalmente incorrectas. Los pronombres clíticos no pueden moverse hacia cualquier parte de la oración; solamente en torno a la frase verbal a la que se refieren, que en este caso es la que incluye al verbo *comprar*. Es decir, debería ser *“me lo habías comprado”*.

Comment: entiendo. Al mismo tiempo, si escribieramos una oración completamente de nuevo (es decir, no refiramos a la pregunta original), sería correcta esta oración: "Me lo habías encontrado un regalo y lo habías comprado"? Con el significado: "You had found a gift for me and had bought it". En la primera parte de esta oración "lo" sería como el pronombre duplicativo (refiriendo a "un regalo").

Comment: No, no funcionaría. No se puede reduplicar el pronombre de objeto directo en este caso. Sí sería posible decir *"El regalo me lo habías encontrado y lo habías comprado"*, ya que en ese caso "el regalo" está desplazado al comienzo de la oración y ahí sí es permisible reduplicar el pronombre. (Tiene que ser "el regalo", no "un regalo". Si no es definido no puede usarse el pronombre reduplicado después. Es complicado.)